# How to get all rows from Page list and convert them to CSV utilizing pxConvertResultsToCSV

Tags: pega

I have a Repeat grid layout, as a source is Report definition. The grid displays twenty row per page. So, if there are thirty-three rows, there are four pages.

I have got a task to export all grid's data to CSV. I have found out the pxConvertResultsToCSV activity. It requires to pass PageList with the properties to convert. I use pgRepPgSubSectionMySectionListB.pxResults to do this. But I have realized, that the property pxResults contains only first twenty elements of pgRepPgSubSectionMySectionListB. But I must export to CSV all the rows. How can I reach this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run your report by calling `pxRetrieveReportData` activity of class `Rule-Obj-Report-Definition` in you acticity

Syntex:- `call Rule-Obj-Report-Definition.pxRetrieveReportData`

It will ask for parameters:-

**pyReportName** :- your report definition name

**pyReportClass**:- class of the report definition

**pyPageName** :- any page name for example `ReportListExport`. This page must be defined in `Pages & Classes` of class `Code-Pega-List`

After successful execution of this step, you will get `ReportListExport.pxResults` in `Clipboard`.

Now use this `pxResults` for export.

---

There is one more activity to export your Report in excel.

Call `pzViewExportToExcel` activity after running your report. And keep `ReportListExport.pyReportDefinition` as step page of this step.

This is preferred one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works if there is a certain report definition. But I am going to provide an universal solution with no specific report definition. So, how could I get a name of current report definition?

Comment: But you can parameterize your activity by passing the report definition name.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old now so I'm sure the OP has probably solved the problem and moved on at this point.  But for future viewers there is an easier way to solve this.

Pega includes a gadget called the "Record Editor" which can be used to display a report definition as an editable data table.  It shows the provided report definition in a simple table as normal but users can also edit the rows, delete the rows and add new ones.  It also includes import and export actions at the top so users can drop the entire resultset being shown in the table to CSV and then re-import changes back in after editing.  You can find more information on this gadget and how to use it [in this community article](https://community.pega.com/knowledgebase/articles/adding-record-editor-gadget-application)

If you simply want to provide an option at the top of a table sourced from a report definition that allows users to export the results as CSV without using the record editor gadget there is an API for that as well.  The activity "pxDownloadDataRecordsAsCSV" in class "PegaAccel-Task-DataTableEditor" does this.  It accepts the class and name of a report definition as parameters, runs that report and serves up the contents as a CSV file.

The second part here isn't too different from AJ's solution it's just an already existing parameterized activity you can use instead of writing one yourself.