# PEGA relief map - data table exported to CSV using JSON

Tags: json, csv, section508, pega

New job, new platform:  Pega.    So Pega is being used to host a relief map of ranchers and farmers for a conservation project.  A data table can be generated with about 20-22 columns.  The developer told me that the export to CSV uses a function exposed by Pega to convert a JSON payload to a .CSV file

the problem is, empty cells in the data table on the browser have a "-" (the dash symbol) because our client doesn't want empty data cells.  The dashes are not carried over to the .CSV export

the second problem is that a column that displays that data in quotations is being exported to .CSV with double quotations.

I have been going over to the code in developer view trying to figure out where and how that data is being exported that particular way but I can't find the exact string.

Does anyone else have experience with Pega using a JSON command to export a .CSV file?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you try to create a `Report Definition` Rule for that Data Table ? If yes, then you will see an action to Export the Report as an PDF or Excel. Try the `Export to Excel` action and see whether the result is coming out properly or not.

Comment: Check few answers already present related to export to csv.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43471934/how-to-get-all-rows-from-page-list-and-convert-them-to-csv-utilizing-pxconvertre and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43354468/how-to-export-repeat-grid-layout-data-to-excel-using-pzrdexportwrapper-in-pega-7